# Why is Runt, the protagonist, smaller than the other giants?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-bfg

I was just watching the [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3691740/) and saw that the BFG is smaller than other giants, why is that?

[image]
(The BFG is the one being held - in one hand - by the big ginger-haired giant.)

If he's a giant and everyone in his world are giants, shouldn't they all be of the same or almost similar height and strength?

Has this been explained anywhere in the movies or the book? I might have missed something

Comment: Are all people the same height?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Read my question. I asked why are they not of the same OR SIMILIAR height and strength. Of the 9-10 giants in the movie, the protagonist is the smallest. He's also the weakest. My question was the reason behind this.

Comment: @BCdotWEB clearly you haven't seen the film.  We're not just talking about a slightly shorter giant here, we're talking _significantly_ shorter and smaller.  I added a pic to help.

Comment: The BFG's name isn't actually Runt.  That's just what the others call him. It's a derogatory term.

Answer (score 8):

The real reason why is that the author made that the plot point for the story. However, the name, Runt, is a huge clue: the "[runt of the litter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runt)" is a puppy, kitten, or similar animal that is MUCH smaller than all the others. Without a lot of help, runts typically die. Sometimes people tease small children by calling them "runt".

The explanation, then, is that for some unknown reason this giant is much smaller than all the others. While this may be rare in the made-up world of the giants, it's not impossible, since this character is like that. I used to tell my children when they balked at story details, "it doesn't happen often, that's why they built a story around it."

Answer (score -1):

I believe that he is smaller because he is a vegetarian and it stunted his growth. As he is the only one who does not eat children, he is also the only one who is tiny.

Comment: You "*believe*" ?  Do you have any evidence to back this up?